# How to input audio using pycord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I am trying to build a pycord bot that accepts audio input and saves it locally to be processed.
But I am unable to record the audio from a voice channel.
I tried doing it myself but ended up using this example by official pycord development

[Pycord-voice record example](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/examples/audio_recording.py)

But then I am hit with this error

```
Ignoring exception in command start:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Sink/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 360, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/Sink/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 919, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/Sink/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 849, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/Sink/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 755, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/home/runner/Sink/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 588, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: sink is a required argument that is missing.
```

Here is my code

```py
import discord
from enum import Enum
import os
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)


connections = {}

class Sinks(Enum):
    mp3 = discord.sinks.MP3Sink()  #Part of code I do not understand 
    wav = discord.sinks.WaveSink()
    pcm = discord.sinks.PCMSink()
    ogg = discord.sinks.OGGSink()
    mka = discord.sinks.MKASink()
    mkv = discord.sinks.MKVSink()
    mp4 = discord.sinks.MP4Sink()
    m4a = discord.sinks.M4ASink()


async def finished_callback(sink, channel: discord.TextChannel, *args):
    recorded_users = [f"<@{user_id}>" for user_id, audio in sink.audio_data.items()]
    await sink.vc.disconnect()
    files = [
        discord.File(audio.file, f"{user_id}.{sink.encoding}")
        for user_id, audio in sink.audio_data.items()
    ]
    await channel.send(
        f"Finished! Recorded audio for {', '.join(recorded_users)}.", files=files
    )


@bot.command()
async def start(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext, sink: Sinks):
    """Record your voice!"""
    voice = ctx.author.voice

    if not voice:
        return await ctx.respond("You're not in a vc right now")

    vc = await voice.channel.connect()
    connections.update({ctx.guild.id: vc})

    vc.start_recording(
        sink.value,
        finished_callback,
        ctx.channel,
    )

    await ctx.respond("The recording has started!")


@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    """Stop recording."""
    if ctx.guild.id in connections:
        vc = connections[ctx.guild.id]
        vc.stop_recording()
        del connections[ctx.guild.id]
        await ctx.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.respond("Not recording in this guild.")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ON")


bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function header tells Pycord what the command name is, and any arguments. You can see the second argument is Sinks, which is an enum. Basically, to run this command, you need to input a file format, like that one listed in the Sinks enum.

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext, sink: Sinks): # <-- This is the sink(aka file format) argument
    """Record your voice!"""

class Sinks(Enum):
    mp3 = discord.sinks.MP3Sink() # All the valid file formats
    wav = discord.sinks.WaveSink()
    pcm = discord.sinks.PCMSink()
    ogg = discord.sinks.OGGSink()
    mka = discord.sinks.MKASink()
    mkv = discord.sinks.MKVSink()
    mp4 = discord.sinks.MP4Sink()
    m4a = discord.sinks.M4ASink()
```

Run the command with `.start mp3` or `.start wav` or etc.

Comment: it gives an error mp3 is not a valid sink 
```ValueError: 'mp3' is not a valid Sinks

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception```

```raise BadArgument(f'Converting to "{name}" failed for parameter "{param.name}".') from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "Sinks" failed for parameter "sink".```